# How to resize camera aspect ratio after rotation?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, video-capture, screen-orientation

I have a little Swift program to capture videos. If I start the app with the phone in Landscape mode, then I get the full screen

[image]

but when I rotate the phone to Portrait, it doesn't fill the whole screen.

[image]

I've tried with resizeAspectFill but it doesn't work. 
I suspect I have to change the aspect ratio when I rotate the screen to the new aspect ratio but can't seem to find any examples which successfully does it.

Can anyone help please?

The sample code looks something like this:

```
    cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

    let orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation

    switch (orientation) {
    case .portrait:
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
    case .landscapeRight:
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
    case .landscapeLeft:
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
    case .portraitUpsideDown:
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
    default:
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
    }

    cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame

    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have constraints for your `imageView`?

Comment: I don't think so. The thing is, if I hold the phone in Portrait mode and start the app, the Portrait aspect ratio is correct but incorrect when I rotate to Landscape mode. If I hold the phone in Landscape mode and start the app, the Landscape aspect ratio is correct but incorrect when I rotate to Portrait mode.

Comment: So it seems you dont have correct constraints for your imageView. Do you create your imageView in VC and set frame equal to view?

Comment: I downloaded a sample code to play with it. From what I can see, there's no imageview. What the code is doing is creating a sublayer and adding that sublayer to the VC. I'm trying out how to change the aspect of the sublayer.

Comment: Show your code plz.

Comment: I've included the code in the main post. That's the only place I can find which sets the orientation. No other place sets the orientation of the camera....Maybe that's the problem: everytime I rotate, I should detect that the camera is rotated and reset the aspect ratio on the sublayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving these code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation

    switch (orientation) {
    case .portrait:
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
    case .landscapeRight:
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
    case .landscapeLeft:
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
    case .portraitUpsideDown:
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
    default:
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
    }

    cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much! I had it in viewWillLayoutSubviews - wrong function! 
One more question: if I go from landscape left to portrait to landscape right, the aspect ratio works and everything is fine. But if I go from landscape left, turn the phone upside down and go straight to landscape right, then the picture becomes upside down. i.e. you can only turn 90 degrees at a time for the picture to be shown correctly (right side up).

Comment: I am not sure about this. I had `.portrait` in default.